Can you Identify the film where a retired cop alters his badge?
I know I'm going to hit myself in the face with a huge "DUH" when someone quickly answers this, but what film is it where a retired police officer removes his old badge and alters it to play cop again? I remember he takes it out from a frame which has his badge and i believe his uniform, and it must have been given to him to honor his career when he retired. The old man then uses whiteout to touch out the red letters that read "RETIRED", and practices flipping the badge open in front of the mirror. I remember the entire scene takes place in a very dark and small apartment and I feel like he is forced to take up this protective mantle against his will to protect a kidnapped child or woman. 
I know this is a mainstream movie and not too obscure so I'm sure it won't take long for someone to identify it.

God, that's going to drive me nuts until I remember what it is

@kristine, you know, I don't think it was. I remember it being a younger, thinner guy. But what is the title of the movie are you talking about? Just to make sure.

Ok, I'm still thinking about this.  Is it maybe not his badge, but like his dad's or something?

@kevin, no, it's definitely his old badge. Ring any bells?

I'm asking over on reddit and Once Upon a Time in Mexico has been suggested.  Do you remember any other details?  Race of the guy?  Genre?  Obviously some kind of cop movie, but was it comedy like Cop-Out?  Really edgy/dark?  Somewhere in between?

Once Upon A Time in Mexico is the movie.  Reuben Blades is the actor.  He's a retired FBI agent and it's actually the "Invalid" on the ID that he's whiting out.  You can see it on Crackle The scene starts at about the 42 minute mark
